# NSDictionary retain crash

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary, storing value by parsing. I am allocating and storing value in `-viewDidLoad`. And accessing the values in `-viewWillAppear`. It works perfectly fine.

Then, I have `UIPageControl` with `UIScrollView`. While scrolling the `UIScrollView`, again I am accessing the same dictionary, it crashes saying

`[CFString respondToSelector:]: send to deallocated....`

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    scoresDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[scoreObj scores]];
}

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {

    if (page < 0) 

        return;

    if (page >= kNumberOfPages)

    return;

    NSLog(@“scoresDict %@”,scoresDict);
}
```

I tried using `retain` in the same function, it didn’t work out. And `copy`, it also didn’t work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: who is retaining scoreObj, and where are you releasing it?

Comment: scoreObj is child object of the class where parsing is done. It is been initialized in `-viewDidLoad` and released in `-dealloc`

Answer (score 0):

You don't say so, but it looks like all of these methods are being called from an instance of your custom UIViewController or UIScrollViewController subclass.

The most likely problem is that this instance itself isn't being retained.

When you first load the view from the nib, both -viewDidLoad and -viewWillAppear are called. It's possible, however, that garbage collection is happening in between those calls and your call to -loadScrollViewWithPage, and that no object has any connection to the view controller instance itself.

If that's the case, using copy or retain on the scoresDict won't solve the problem. You need to make sure that you are copying or retaining the view controller instance itself. Figure out what object needs to be retaining your view controller and make sure it is being retained.

A quick way to test whether this is the problem or not: create a "myViewController" property in your application delegate. In viewDidLoad, add a line:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setMyViewController:self];
```

If this fixes your problem, it means the problem was the view controller getting released. That doesn't mean this is your best solution, though--it's just a diagnostic. You need to figure out what should be retaining your view controller and make sure it does so.

Comment: One note I just thought of: It's also possible your UIViewController is being released due to low memory conditions--in which case you would need to implement viewWillUnload to save the value somewhere else (or just re-jig your code so it's saved somewhere else in the first place). But based on your symptoms the above seems more likely.